# tool to view XML as a tree?

Tags: java, xml, ontology

Is there any java based tool to view the XML file in the form of binary/ternary tree?

I need a pictorial view of tree.. in the form of nodes and edges.. like a graph..

please help me

Comment: I need a pictorial view of tree.. in the form of nodes and edges.. like a graph.. please help

Comment: It hasn't even been 20 minutes yet, give people a chance to see your post.

Comment: Just added few more details to my query

Comment: Where? I don't see any edits....

Comment: why did you tag your question with "ontology"? is it a mistake? are yo perhaps trying to visualize the XML serialization of an ontology?

Answer (score 3):

If you have any XML/XSLT skills you could transform your XML to SVG. This method would allow you to draw anything you want. See an example [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/09/08/tree.html). Once you have the SVG file you can upload it into Google docs or view it in Photoshop or [embed](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp) it in an html document.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse (IDE)  [www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org)

> The XML editor also has a Design view. This view has the following features:
>
> - List item
>
>   The XML file is represented simultaneously as a table and a tree. This helps make navigation and editing easier.
> - Content and attribute values can be edited directly in the table cells, while pop-up menus on the tree nodes give alternatives that are valid for that location. For example, the Add Child menu item will list only those elements from a DTD or XML schema which would be valid children at that point (as long as grammar constraints are on).

Comment: thank u, but I want to produce XML in a graph form as output.. not in design time..

Comment: You "want to produce XML"? Are you asking for help on how to _write_ an XML viewing tool?

Comment: My query is is there any graph based XML viewing tool exists?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JUNG, http://jung.sourceforge.net/. I've used that toolkit to create an XPath visualizer, which was kind of fun. Don't remember if there was a ready XML to tree example, or not, though.

Answer (score 0):

XML Spy would be good, but it's not free.

You can open XML in any browser and see it rendered as a hierarchy.

Comment: I dont want it be a tree as in browser.. i want pictorial view of tree with nodes and edges